# Attach a PDF for emailing in excel which changes each time macro is run

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which copies some sheets from a Workbook and then emails it.

I can save it as a set filename and use that however I would like to keep the file name for the PDF also.

So basically the macro

- copies 2 sheets
- saves it as a filename relevant to E1, saves it in PDF.
- opens Outlook and tries to email the two saved files.

It attaches the active book, but I can't make it attached the PDF with the same name. I can save it as say `Revisit.pdf` and that attaches fine, however I need the filename to change.

Any ideas would be gratefully received.

That's my current code:

```
Sub EmailWithOutlook()
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim shtName As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Delete all PDF fies in P:\field service\JJohns\FOF Data\TEMP
    Call killPDF

    Call Firstentry


    ' Sheets("Daily Sheets").Select
    ' activeSheet.Copy
    ' ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "P:\Field Service\JJohns\Engineer Revisits\" & Range("E1").Value

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    Sheets("Dashboard").Name = "Dashboard"
    Sheets(Array("Dashboard", "Daily Sheets")).Select
    Sheets("Daily Sheets").Activate
    Sheets(Array("Dashboard", "Daily Sheets")).Copy
    Sheets("Daily Sheets").Select
    Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Team Leader")).Select
    Selection.Cut
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Date of update")).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("E1").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "P:\Field Service\JJohns\Engineer Revisits\" & Range("E1").Value

    'Save PDF VERSION

    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "P:\Field Service\JJohns\FOF data\TEMP\" & Range("E1").Value, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    ' SAVE PDF AS REVISITS
      '  ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
   '     "P:\Field Service\JJohns\FOF Data\Temp\Revisits.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard _
    '    , IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish _
     '   :=False
    ' Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show


    'Create and show the Outlook mail item
    Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Mail = App.CreateItem(0)
    With Mail
        'Uncomment the line below to hard code a recipient
         .To = "XXXXXXXXX"
        ' .CC = "XXXXXXXXXX"
        'Uncomment the line below to hard code a subject
        .Subject = Range("Dashboard!E1").Value
        'Uncomment the lines below to hard code a body
        ' .body = "Hi Mark" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        '   "Please find attached the North East updates"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        **.Attachments.Add "P:\Field Service\JJohns\FOF Data\Temp\" & Range(E1).Value, .PDF**
        .Display
    End With

    'Delete the temporary file
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Kill ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Restore screen updating and release Outlook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Attachments.Add "P:\Field Service\JJohns\FOF Data\Temp\" & Range(E1).Value & ".pdf"`

Comment: This still errors out., any other ideas?

Comment: Is the file actually created with the `.pdf` extension? If not, try: `.Attachments.Add "P:\Field Service\JJohns\FOF Data\Temp\" & Range(E1).Value`

Comment: However, you may want to update the filename of the file produced in the `ExportAsFixedFormat` call: `FileName:= "P:\Field Service\JJohns\FOF data\TEMP\" & Range("E1").Value & ".pdf"`.

Comment: yeah it saves it fine, it just error's when trying to attach it to the email. The .xlsx attaches, and if I save the PDF as a set file name it attaches fine, but I can't get it to attach using the "E1" cell reference

Comment: Sorry if  I hadn't made my self clear above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this

```
 'Save PDF VERSION
 Dim s as string
 s =  "P:\Field Service\JJohns\FOF data\TEMP\" & Range("E1").Value & ".pdf"
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
    s, Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

 'more code here

 .Attachments.Add s
```

Also I assume you've checked that the file does exist at that location when it errors?